# Converting mixed L1/L2 problem with Constraints to Quadratic Program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, dual-spaces, quadratic-programming

I am considering the following problem:

$$
\min_u \frac{1}{2}\|Au\|_2^2 + \lambda\|u\|_1, \quad \text{s.t.} \quad 
Cu = b, \|u\|_{\infty} \leq 1,
$$
where $u\in\mathbb{R}^m, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+, b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The main goal is to convert this into a quadratic program. In the case of *no* equality constraints, I have the following solution. Rewrite the problem as

$$
\min_{u,v} \frac{1}{2}\|Au\|_2^2 + \lambda\|v\|_1, \quad \text{s.t.} \quad u = v
$$

The Lagrangian is then $L(u,v,\mu) = \frac{1}{2}\|Au\|_2^2 + \lambda\|v\|_1 + \mu^\intercal(u-v)$, where $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^m$. The lagrange dual function is then

$$
g(\mu) = \inf_{u,v} L(u,v,\mu)
$$

First, compute the infimum over $u$, by taking the gradient and setting it to zero, i.e.

$$
\nabla_u L(u,v,\mu) = A^\intercal A u + \mu = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{u^* = -(A^\intercal A)^{-1}\mu}
$$

Next, compute the infimum over $v$, i.e.

$$
\inf_v \lambda\|v\| - \mu^\intercal v = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if} \quad \|\mu\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda\\
-\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, the dual problem becomes

$$
\max_{\|\mu\|_{\infty}\leq\lambda} \frac{1}{2}\|A(A^\intercal A)^{-1}\mu\|_2^2 - \mu^\intercal (A^\intercal A)^{-1}\mu
$$

Simplifying this, we get

$$
\max_{\|\mu\|_{\infty}\leq\lambda} -\frac{1}{2}\mu^\intercal(A^\intercal A)^{-\intercal} \mu = \min_{\|\mu\|_{\infty}\leq\lambda} \mu^\intercal B \mu,
$$
where $B = \frac{1}{2}(A^\intercal A)^{-\intercal}$. This is clearly a quadratic program. I want to follow a similar procedure to my problem at hand, but I don't see a clear way to do it.

In my current problem, we can write the lagrange dual function as

$$
g(\mu_1,\mu_2) = \inf_{u,v} \frac{1}{2}\|Au\|_2^2 + \lambda\|v\|_1 + \mu_1^\intercal(u-v) + \mu_2^\intercal(Cv-b) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \|u\|_{\infty} \leq 1
$$

The infimum over $u$ is now

$$
\begin{align}
&\inf_u \{\frac{1}{2}u^\intercal A^\intercal A u + \mu_1^\intercal u : \|u\|_{\infty} \leq 1\}\\
&= \inf_u \{u^\intercal \bar{A} u : \|u\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \} - \sup_u \{(-\mu_1^\intercal u) : \|u\|_{\infty} \leq 1\}\\
&= \inf_u \{u^\intercal \bar{A} u : \|u\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \} - \|\mu_1\|_1
\end{align},
$$
where $\bar{A} = \frac{1}{2}A^\intercal A$, and the definition of the dual norm is used to simplify the second term. My problem is that I am stuck with that infimum in the first term, and don't see how to simplify this further. The infimum over $v$ becomes

$$
\inf_v \lambda\|v\|_1 - (\mu_1^\intercal - \mu_2^\intercal C) v = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if} \quad \|\mu_1^\intercal - \mu_2^\intercal C\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda\\
-\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The main goal is to convert this into a quadratic program". But this already is a quadratic program. Is there some special restricted form you want to get (and why?)?

Comment: Well, I’m hoping to simplify the problem a bit because there is that $l_1$ norm. In the case where the system had no constraints, you can turn the above problem into a simpler quadratic program (only quadratic form).

Comment: Yes but since you already have linear constraints adding the l1 norm is not a problem. It is just a few more linear inequalities. At least from a practical point of view.